# "cut" a div after rotation?

Tags: html, css

I have created a message tool tip like : 
[image]

But it consists of an image of :

[image]

And a regular div to the right. (with text inside)

However , I prefer not to do it with image. I want to create the triangle part with rotated div.

I've managed to do it [**here**](http://jsbin.com/ohuguw/4/edit)  by creating a simple div and rotate it:

```
   transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

and the result is :

[image]

However (and this is my question) -- can I remove the right part of the rotated div  , so i'll only have :

[image]

Is it possible ?

*p.s. - I know thtat I can hide the right part with div by using another div with position relative/absolute. but I want to know if there is a solution with removing the right part. (or maybe  , is there any code to create triangle ?). Also lets assume the angle is 90 deg. like in the red div.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without rotating the element, wrap this inside a position relative element, and use position absolute to set it right

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R3kkN/)

```
.left {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right:10px solid #001744; 
}
```

Comment: amazing. ( still digesting it) . but how come the border-top is not a pure rectangle of border ? how can a border create triangle ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Good read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work

Comment: @RoyiNamir You can see some amazing examples here too http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/